# Can I put my public_html folder under source control?

Tags: html

This would allow me to update the folder in one click when I test the code on my development system. Is it possible and is it a good idea?

Answer (score 5):

"Is it possible" Yes, you can put any directory under version control. If it is a good idea depends on what you are doing with it. I'm using the Netbeans feature "copy project data to another dir" instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you do so, be sure you block access to the source control system's directories and files. Here's an example of [how to block access to Subversion directories in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398008/deny-access-to-svn-folders-on-apache); it will be similar for other SCC systems/web servers.

Comment: I didn't precise it as he said it was for the development system, but it's obviously recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, but it would maybe be easier to use tools like [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) to deploy your code. It would be the same tool to deploy it for development and production, just in declaring different targeted servers.